# Compilation problem after upgrade from Play! Framework 2.5 to 2.6

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I am in the process of upgrading my Play! Application from 2.5 to 2.6.
However, I have spend two days fixing some of the changes between those two version, but keep running into the following problems ( a snipped of the errors, there are many, all the same):

```
[error] GET     /intercom/distributionStatus/:file controllers.Intercom.distributionStatus(file: String)
[error] myProject/conf/routes:62: stable identifier required, but ReverseIntercom.this.play found.
[error] GET     /intercom/play/:file    controllers.Intercom.play(file: String)
[error] myProject/conf/routes:62: missing argument list for method play in class ReverseIntercom
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `play _` or `play(_)` instead of `play`.
[error] GET     /intercom/play/:file    controllers.Intercom.play(file: String)
[error] myProject/conf/routes:61: stable identifier required, but ReverseIntercom.this.play found.
[error] GET     /intercom/delete/:file  controllers.Intercom.delete(file: String)
[error] myProject/conf/routes:61: missing argument list for method play in class ReverseIntercom
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `play _` or `play(_)` instead of `play`.
[error] GET     /intercom/delete/:file  controllers.Intercom.delete(file: String)
[error] myProject/conf/routes:66: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/startAudioUpload/:fileName controllers.Intercom.startAudioUpload(fileName: String)
[error] GET     /intercom/startAudioPlay/:file controllers.Intercom.startAudioPlay(file: String)
[error] myProject/conf/routes:75: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/stopAudioForDevice/:file controllers.Intercom.stopAudioPlayForDevice(file: String)
[error] myProject/conf/routes:74: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/stopAudio/:file controllers.Intercom.stopAudioPlay(file: String)
[error] myProject/conf/routes:65: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/distributionStatus/:file controllers.Intercom.distributionStatus(file: String)
[error] myProject/conf/routes:62: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/play/:file    controllers.Intercom.play(file: String)

[error] 22 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] application - 
! @7fb9gmm98 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[stable identifier required, but ReverseIntercom.this.play found.]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
```

I have made no changes to my Routes file, and already had `routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator` in Play! 2.5.

This is a snipped of my routes file:

```
# Intercom
GET     /intercom               controllers.Intercom.index()
POST    /intercom/upload        controllers.Intercom.doUpload()
GET     /intercom/delete/:file  controllers.Intercom.delete(file: String)
GET     /intercom/play/:file    controllers.Intercom.play(file: String)
GET     /intercom/record        controllers.Intercom.record()
GET     /intercom/fileList      controllers.Intercom.fileList()
GET     /intercom/distributionStatus/:file controllers.Intercom.distributionStatus(file: String)
GET     /intercom/startAudioUpload/:fileName controllers.Intercom.startAudioUpload(fileName: String)
GET     /intercom/startAudioPlay/:file controllers.Intercom.startAudioPlay(file: String)
```

I am missing something in my migration?
It must be something small, but at this stage I might have to go back to 2.5 as I cannot seem to find what the issue is to get a normal build. Any help is really really appreciated!

[EDIT]
I used clean and later invalidated all caches in IDEAL. That rebuild it, but I had to delete the routes that cause the error. The project builds, but as soon as I put them back in, it fails again.

As requested a dump of the set 'clean' and then 'compile' command.

```
info] Updating {file:MyProject/}knockadoonserver...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.12.10 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-enhancer;1.1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.18.2-GA ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.12;1.3.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.12;1.0.6 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-ebean_2.12;4.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-jdbc_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc-api_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-netty-utils;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.25 ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#jul-to-slf4j;1.7.25 ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#jcl-over-slf4j;1.7.25 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-streams_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.reactivestreams#reactive-streams;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-stream_2.12;2.5.3 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.12;2.5.3 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.3.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-java8-compat_2.12;0.8.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe#ssl-config-core_2.12;0.2.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-slf4j_2.12;2.5.3 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.8.9 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.8.9 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.8.9 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype#jackson-datatype-jdk8;2.8.9 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype#jackson-datatype-jsr310;2.8.9 ...
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.10 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-functional_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12.10 ...
[info] Resolving org.typelevel#macro-compat_2.12;1.1.1 ...
[info] Resolving joda-time#joda-time;2.9.9 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.guava#guava;22.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.9 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.errorprone#error_prone_annotations;2.0.18 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.j2objc#j2objc-annotations;1.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.codehaus.mojo#animal-sniffer-annotations;1.14 ...
[info] Resolving io.jsonwebtoken#jjwt;0.7.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.6 ...
[info] Resolving javax.transaction#jta;1.1 ...
[info] Resolving javax.inject#javax.inject;1 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.12;1.0.6 ...
[info] Resolving com.jolbox#bonecp;0.8.0.RELEASE ...
[info] Resolving com.zaxxer#HikariCP;2.6.3 ...
[info] Resolving com.googlecode.usc#jdbcdslog;1.0.6.2 ...
[info] Resolving tyrex#tyrex;1.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.reflections#reflections;0.9.11 ...
[info] Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.21.0-GA ...
[info] Resolving net.jodah#typetools;0.5.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc-evolutions_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving io.ebean#ebean;10.2.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.jetbrains#annotations;13.0 ...
[info] Resolving io.ebean#persistence-api;2.2.1 ...
[info] Resolving io.ebean#ebean-annotation;2.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.avaje#avaje-datasource-api;1.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.avaje#avaje-datasource;2.1.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.avaje#avaje-classpath-scanner-api;2.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.avaje#avaje-classpath-scanner;2.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving io.ebean#ebean-dbmigration;10.1.6 ...
[info] Resolving com.h2database#h2;1.4.193 ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;[1.7.1,1.7.99) ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;[1.7.1,1.7.99) ...
[info] Resolving org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.6 ...
[info] Resolving io.ebean#ebean-agent;10.2.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-forms_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.hibernate#hibernate-validator;5.4.1.Final ...
[info] Resolving javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.Final ...
[info] Resolving org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;3.3.0.Final ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml#classmate;1.3.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-context;4.3.9.RELEASE ...
[info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-core;4.3.9.RELEASE ...
[info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-beans;4.3.9.RELEASE ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#filters-helpers_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-logback_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.2.3 ...
[info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.2.3 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-akka-http-server_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-http-core_2.12;10.0.8 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-parsing_2.12;10.0.8 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-ehcache_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving net.sf.ehcache#ehcache;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.ehcache#jcache;1.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving javax.cache#cache-api;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-ahc-ws_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-ws_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-ws-standalone_2.12;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe#ssl-config-core_2.12;0.2.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-ws-standalone-xml_2.12;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-ws-standalone-json_2.12;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-ahc-ws-standalone_2.12;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#cachecontrol_2.12;1.1.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.joda#joda-convert;1.7 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#shaded-asynchttpclient;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#shaded-oauth;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving mysql#mysql-connector-java;8.0.19 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.protobuf#protobuf-java;3.6.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.5.12 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.4.13 ...
[info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.2 ...
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.11 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.api-client#google-api-client;1.30.9 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.oauth-client#google-oauth-client;1.30.5 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.http-client#google-http-client;1.34.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.j2objc#j2objc-annotations;1.3 ...
[info] Resolving io.opencensus#opencensus-api;0.24.0 ...
[info] Resolving io.grpc#grpc-context;1.22.1 ...
[info] Resolving io.opencensus#opencensus-contrib-http-util;0.24.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.http-client#google-http-client-jackson2;1.34.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.http-client#google-http-client;1.34.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.guava#guava;28.2-android ...
[info] Resolving com.google.guava#failureaccess;1.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.guava#listenablefuture;9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava ...
[info] Resolving org.checkerframework#checker-compat-qual;2.5.5 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.errorprone#error_prone_annotations;2.3.4 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.10.2 ...
[info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.6 ...
[info] Resolving org.imgscalr#imgscalr-lib;4.2 ...
[info] Resolving net.twasi#obs-websocket-java;1.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty.websocket#websocket-client;9.4.8.v20171121 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-client;9.4.8.v20171121 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;9.4.8.v20171121 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;9.4.8.v20171121 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;9.4.8.v20171121 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-xml;9.4.8.v20171121 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty.websocket#websocket-common;9.4.8.v20171121 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty.websocket#websocket-api;9.4.8.v20171121 ...
[info] Resolving org.junit.jupiter#junit-jupiter-api;5.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.apiguardian#apiguardian-api;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.opentest4j#opentest4j;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.junit.platform#junit-platform-commons;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.code.gson#gson;2.8.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.yaml#snakeyaml;1.17 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-guice_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.inject#guice;4.1.0 ...
[info] Resolving aopalliance#aopalliance;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;4.1.0 ...
[info] Resolving junit#junit;4.12 ...
[info] Resolving org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3 ...
[info] Resolving com.novocode#junit-interface;0.11 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-core;3.2.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-remote-driver;3.3.1 ...
[info] Resolving cglib#cglib-nodep;3.2.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-exec;1.3 ...
[info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#jna-platform;4.1.0 ...
[info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#jna;4.1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.atteo.classindex#classindex;3.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#htmlunit-driver;2.27 ...
[info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.27 ...
[info] Resolving xalan#xalan;2.7.2 ...
[info] Resolving xalan#serializer;2.7.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpmime;4.5.3 ...
[info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit-core-js;2.27 ...
[info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#neko-htmlunit;2.27 ...
[info] Resolving xerces#xercesImpl;2.11.0 ...
[info] Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.4.01 ...
[info] Resolving net.sourceforge.cssparser#cssparser;0.9.23 ...
[info] Resolving org.w3c.css#sac;1.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-api;3.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-support;3.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-remote-driver;3.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-firefox-driver;3.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.12;2.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-doc_2.12;1.8.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.pegdown#pegdown;1.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-java;1.1.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-core;1.1.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm;5.0.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-tree;5.0.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-analysis;5.0.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-util;5.0.3 ...
[info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12.10 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.6 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.12 ...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn] 
[warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android is selected over {22.0, 26.0-android, 28.1-android, 20.0, 15.0}
[warn]      +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.34.2   (depends on 28.2-android)
[warn]      +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.30.9     (depends on 28.2-android)
[warn]      +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.30.5 (depends on 28.1-android)
[warn]      +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.34.0   (depends on 28.1-android)
[warn]      +- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-http-util:0.24.0  (depends on 26.0-android)
[warn]      +- com.jolbox:bonecp:0.8.0.RELEASE                    (depends on 22.0)
[warn]      +- org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11                 (depends on 22.0)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.0                  (depends on 22.0)
[warn] 
[warn]  * com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2 is selected over 1.3.9
[warn]      +- com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android                (depends on 3.0.2)
[warn]      +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.30.5 (depends on 3.0.2)
[warn]      +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.34.2   (depends on 3.0.2)
[warn]      +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.34.0   (depends on 3.0.2)
[warn]      +- com.google.guava:guava:22.0                        (depends on 1.3.9)
[warn] 
[warn]  * org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 is selected over {1.7.25, 1.7.22, 1.6.1, 1.7.7, [1.7,1.8), 1.7.12, 1.5.10, 1.7.2, 1.7.23}
[warn]      +- io.ebean:ebean:10.2.3                              (depends on 1.7.30)
[warn]      +- org.ehcache:jcache:1.0.1                           (depends on 1.6.1)
[warn]      +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.4                      (depends on 1.6.1)
[warn]      +- com.jolbox:bonecp:0.8.0.RELEASE                    (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-ahc-ws-standalone_2.12:1.0.0 (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25                      (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-netty-utils:2.6.0           (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- com.googlecode.usc:jdbcdslog:1.0.6.2               (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- org.avaje:avaje-classpath-scanner:2.2.2            (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.25                    (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.0                  (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- org.avaje:avaje-datasource-api:1.1                 (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3               (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:cachecontrol_2.12:1.1.2          (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.12:2.5.3            (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn]      +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.6.3                          (depends on 1.7.25)
[warn] 
[warn]  * org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations is evicted completely
[warn]      +- com.google.guava:guava:22.0                        (depends on 1.14)
[warn] 
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.3 is selected over 2.4.19
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-streams_2.12:2.6.0          (depends on 2.5.3)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-ws-standalone_2.12:1.0.0    (depends on 2.5.3)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core_2.12:10.0.8       (depends on 2.4.19)
[warn] 
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.3 is selected over 2.4.19
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.12:2.5.3            (depends on 2.5.3)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.3           (depends on 2.5.3)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.0                  (depends on 2.5.3)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing_2.12:10.0.8         (depends on 2.4.19)
[warn] 
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Compiling 83 Scala sources and 104 Java sources to MyProject/target/scala-2.12/classes...
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:66: stable identifier required, but ReverseIntercom.this.play found.
[error] GET     /intercom/startAudioUpload/:fileName    controllers.Intercom.startAudioUpload(fileName: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:66: missing argument list for method play in class ReverseIntercom
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `play _` or `play(_)` instead of `play`.
[error] GET     /intercom/startAudioUpload/:fileName    controllers.Intercom.startAudioUpload(fileName: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:67: stable identifier required, but ReverseIntercom.this.play found.
[error] GET     /intercom/startAudioPlay/:file          controllers.Intercom.startAudioPlay(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:67: missing argument list for method play in class ReverseIntercom
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `play _` or `play(_)` instead of `play`.
[error] GET     /intercom/startAudioPlay/:file          controllers.Intercom.startAudioPlay(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:75: stable identifier required, but ReverseIntercom.this.play found.
[error] GET     /intercom/stopAudioForDevice/:file controllers.Intercom.stopAudioPlayForDevice(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:75: missing argument list for method play in class ReverseIntercom
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `play _` or `play(_)` instead of `play`.
[error] GET     /intercom/stopAudioForDevice/:file controllers.Intercom.stopAudioPlayForDevice(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:74: stable identifier required, but ReverseIntercom.this.play found.
[error] GET     /intercom/stopAudio/:file controllers.Intercom.stopAudioPlay(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:74: missing argument list for method play in class ReverseIntercom
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `play _` or `play(_)` instead of `play`.
[error] GET     /intercom/stopAudio/:file controllers.Intercom.stopAudioPlay(file: String)
[error] Server/conf/routes:65: stable identifier required, but ReverseIntercom.this.play found.
[error] GET     /intercom/distributionStatus/:file      controllers.Intercom.distributionStatus(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:65: missing argument list for method play in class ReverseIntercom
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `play _` or `play(_)` instead of `play`.
[error] GET     /intercom/distributionStatus/:file      controllers.Intercom.distributionStatus(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:62: stable identifier required, but ReverseIntercom.this.play found.
[error] GET     /intercom/play/:file    controllers.Intercom.play(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:62: missing argument list for method play in class ReverseIntercom
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `play _` or `play(_)` instead of `play`.
[error] GET     /intercom/play/:file    controllers.Intercom.play(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:61: stable identifier required, but ReverseIntercom.this.play found.
[error] GET     /intercom/delete/:file  controllers.Intercom.delete(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:61: missing argument list for method play in class ReverseIntercom
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `play _` or `play(_)` instead of `play`.
[error] GET     /intercom/delete/:file  controllers.Intercom.delete(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:66: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/startAudioUpload/:fileName    controllers.Intercom.startAudioUpload(fileName: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:67: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/startAudioPlay/:file          controllers.Intercom.startAudioPlay(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:75: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/stopAudioForDevice/:file controllers.Intercom.stopAudioPlayForDevice(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:74: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/stopAudio/:file controllers.Intercom.stopAudioPlay(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:65: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/distributionStatus/:file      controllers.Intercom.distributionStatus(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:62: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/play/:file    controllers.Intercom.play(file: String)
[error] MyProject/conf/routes:61: value api is not a member of play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute
[error] GET     /intercom/delete/:file  controllers.Intercom.delete(file: String)
[error] 21 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 21 s, completed 02-Apr-2020 22:40:47
```

Comment: Could you run `; clean ; compile` in SBT and post the output? Also it would be helpful to show what you did change in your project.

Comment: Thanks cbley. I did get the same output after cleaning, but now when I comment out the offending Controller the system start building, so that is a great step forward. I will resolve the other issues (mainly depreciated items now obsolete and some changes to the use of Static Classes which now need Modules in order the Inject. I will post back when I have a stable build and add those classes in again.

Comment: @cbley I did get the project to build/compile without the routes that give the problem. The class itself was included in the build. As soon at I uncomment the routes (and the link in the templates revering to them) it gives the same result.

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is in the templates? how do the links look?

Comment: I think it has to be the routes. An example of a link is @routes.Intercom.play(file.getName), but I had to comment them out in the template because it would naturally fail if I comment the route out of the routes file.
Can it be because the variable is a String? I have two in my routes file that are a String but do work, but all the routes that fail have a String as the variable.

Comment: Could you perhaps remove the ` : String` type annotations from all parameters in the routes file. These should not be required. You could have a look at the generated files in `target/scala-2.12/routes` - maybe that gives you a clue why the compiler rejects the code.

Comment: I tried removing the String, but it did not make a difference. In target/scala-2.12/routes the reverse routes for the items given problems is longer/different:
// @LINE:62
def play(file:String): Call = {
      
 Call("GET", _prefix + { _defaultPrefix } + "intercom/play/" + play.core.routing.dynamicString(implicitly[play.api.mvc.PathBindable[String]].unbind("file", file)))
    }

Comment: Could you put that code into the question please, it is unreadable in comments. Also a bit more context would be good, this is only one commented line... ?

Comment: Maybe that is just a name clash? Try to rename your method, choose something other than "play"...